# Joining arrays using references when defining a new data structure

Tags: arrays, perl

First post here for me :)

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I would like to find out.

Given the following code...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %email_addresses = (
    'fred' => [
        '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@domain.com>',
        '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@hotmail.com>'
    ],
    'jane' => [
        '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@domain.com>',
        '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@hotmail.com>',
        '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@somwhere.com>'
    ],
    'tom' => [
        '"Tom Jones" <tom.jones@domain.com>'
    ]
);

my %recipients = (
    'success' => [
        $email_addresses{'fred'},
        $email_addresses{'jane'}
    ],
    'failure' => [
        $email_addresses{'tom'}
    ]
);

print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%recipients], ['recipients']);
```

The output is

```
$recipients = {
                'success' => [
                               [
                                 '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@domain.com>',
                                 '"Fred Blogs" <fred@hotmail.com>'
                               ],
                               [
                                 '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@domain.com>',
                                 '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@hotmail.com>',
                                 '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@somwhere.com>'
                               ]
                             ],
                'failure' => [
                               [
                                 '"Tom Jones" <tom.jones@domain.com>'
                               ]
                             ]
              };
```

The result is that both `$recipients{'success'}` and `$recipients{'failure'}` are two dimensional arrays, however this is not what I want. I would like them to be one dimensional arrays.

That is, for `$recipients{'success'}`, I want the list of Jane's email addresses to be appended to the list of Fred's email addresses resulting in a one dimensional array containing 5 elements. Similarly, `$recipients{'failure'}` would be a one dimensional array containing only 1 element.

So, I want it to look like this...

```
$recipients = {
                'success' => [
                               '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@domain.com>',
                               '"Fred Blogs" <fred@hotmail.com>',
                               '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@domain.com>',
                               '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@hotmail.com>',
                               '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@somwhere.com>'
                             ],
                'failure' => [
                               '"Tom Jones" <tom.jones@domain.com>'
                             ]
              };
```

**Now here's the catch**... I want to know if this can be done at the point where I define `my %recipients` - all in one statement.

I know I can achieve what I want programmatically after the definition using additional statements, but I'm curious to know if it can be done all in one.  I've tried various combinations of (), [], {} and dereferencing but nothing has worked.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially wanting to flatten a list of array references.  Yes, that is easily accomplished.

I would advise that you just use map and pass a list of keys that you want to translate like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %email_addresses = (
    'fred' => [
        '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@domain.com>',
        '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@hotmail.com>',
    ],
    'jane' => [
        '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@domain.com>',
        '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@hotmail.com>',
        '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@somwhere.com>',
    ],
    'tom' => [
        '"Tom Jones" <tom.jones@domain.com>',
    ]
);

my %recipients = (
    'success' => [map @{$email_addresses{$_}}, qw(fred jane)],
    'failure' => [map @{$email_addresses{$_}}, qw(tom)],
);

print Data::Dumper->Dump([\%recipients], ['recipients']);
```

Outputs:

```
$recipients = {
                'success' => [
                               '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@domain.com>',
                               '"Fred Blogs" <fred.blogs@hotmail.com>',
                               '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@domain.com>',
                               '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@hotmail.com>',
                               '"Jane Smith" <jane.smith@somwhere.com>'
                             ],
                'failure' => [
                               '"Tom Jones" <tom.jones@domain.com>'
                             ]
              };
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I hadn't thought of using map.  Thank you very much.

Comment: `Data::Dumper`? Miller? Who are you?? `:P`

Comment: Cute. :P  Yep, I might have a near religious preference for [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) because of its superior format.  But I can the core library sometimes, especially if the OP uses it in their post. :)

Comment: @jaypal: I'm not grasping the context of your comment about `Data::Dumper`.  Is there something wrong with using it?

Comment: @protogen Sorry it was an out of context side joke for miller. Nothing wrong with Data::Dumper. It's a fantastic module. Miller usually prefers to use Data::Dump (another useful module similar to Data::Dumper) in his answers.

Comment: @jaypal Ah, I see. Actually, I'm glad I asked because I totally missed the subtle difference. Thanks. I'll check out `Data::Dump`.

Comment: Data::Dump tends to be slightly more compact and human readable.